# Spatie Media Library - Delete originals after coversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

Is it possible to delete the original files after image conversion using Spatie Media Library (v7) - for example, the client uploads huge resolution files, but we only need them about 1000px wide and dont want to store the huge originals.

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is no. You have to do it manually yourself

A) save one of the smaller images back as the main.
B) manually code a delete or unlink of file

```
unlink($media->getPath());
```